# Null Pointer Exception using setAdapter with a cursor adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to use the cursor adapter but I have a null pointer exception when I call `setAdapter`, I can't figure out what the problem is. Here the code:

Main fragment:

```java
public class GroupsFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView mGroupList;
private GroupAdapter mGroupAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shedule, container, false);

    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    GroupsDB databaseHelper = new GroupsDB(getActivity());

    mGroupList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listGroup);

    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getGroupList();
    mGroupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(getActivity(), cursor, true);

    mGroupList.setAdapter(mGroupAdapter);   //<---NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

    databaseHelper.close();

    Button buttonSend = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.AddGroupButton);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             AddGroup();
         }
     });

}

private void AddGroup() {

}

}
```

Function that return the cursor in order to have only the names of the column GI.GROUP_NAME

```java
public Cursor getGroupList() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, GI.TABLE_NAME,
                            new String[] { GI._ID , GI.GROUP_NAME },
                            null, null,
                            GI.GROUP_NAME , null, null, null);
    db.close();
    return cursor;      

}
```

Finally the custom adapter:

```java
public class GroupAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public GroupAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, Boolean f) {
    super(context, c, f);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.groupItem);
    name.setText(cursor.getString(1));
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_item, parent, false);
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: onActivityCreated is probably called before onCreateView

Comment: Looks like `mGroupList` is probably `null`. Check that you have the right `id`

Comment: does fragment_shedule contain listGroup?

Comment: Provide the log & also provide snapshot with line number.

Comment: @codeMagic the 'id' is correct

Comment: @blackbelt I don't understand, what is fragment_schedule? thanks!

Comment: @user2696917 - it's the layout file that you are inflating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 mGroupList.setAdapter(mGroupAdapter);
```

From this line either mGroupList is null else mGroupAdapter is null.

You should Check your layout file for ListView id

else

Share your log cat It will help to understand the problem more clearly.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

I think You should use getReadableDatabase();

Here you are only performing query on DB.

Comment: it was inflating the wrong layout in 'onCreateView', thank you for the answers.

Comment: Thanks for Marking my ans as it will help others.